# Need to backup remote database using mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I tried to backup the database of a remote server using `automysqlbackup`.

From this platform, I learnt it was not possible without ssh and I need to back it up on a remote machine and then rsync or scp to my local machine, so I am now working with `mysqldump`.

The size of the database is almost 12GB.

```
mysqldump -h 192.168.10.209 -u user -ppassword testdb   > dump.sql
```

I tried backing it up and due to internet issues I have been disconnected twice already., and got this error once:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `helmet`': Lost connection to MySQL server during query (2013)
```

Is there way to continue from where it got disconnected using `msyqldump`?

I also read that `mysqldump` is not good for such a big database backup but I need to test it from here only at this moment.

Are there any options that can be used to make it work smoothly and backup my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cant continue your failed backup. When mysqldump returns a failed status you have to start over again.

My first recommendation is to compress your script before transmitting it

```
mysqldump -h 192.168.10.209 -u user -ppassword testdb | gzip > dump.sql.gz
```

Another recommendation is to connect to the remote server via ssh, then make the backup in the remote server (never will fail for network issues because is a local backup) and, in the last step you could transmit the file (after compress of course).

Other than that, the other 2 options more used are PERCONA XTRA BACKUP and MYSQL ENTERPRISE BACKUP but there are also high prices involved.

Comment: That shrinks the local I/O, but it does not cut down on the bandwidth needed from the remote host.  To improve both, you need something like `ssh "mysqudump ... | gzip" > dump.sql.gz`

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestions. will try to compress it but regarding ssh, i don't have ssh access to the remote server.